# CodeIgniter 3 multi language route

Tags: codeigniter

Here is my route

```
//http://example.com/link
$route['link']                        = 'controller/method';    

//http://example.com/link/india
$route['link/(:any)']                 = 'controller/method/$1'; 

//http://example.com/link/india/delhi
$route['link/(:any)/(:any)']          = 'controller/method/$1/$2';



//http://example.com/en/link
$route['(:any)/link']                 = 'controller/method/$1';

//http://example.com/en/link/india
$route['(:any)/link/(:any)']          = 'controller/method/$1/$2';

//http://example.com/en/link/india/delhi
$route['(:any)/link/(:any)/(:any)']   = 'controller/method/$1/$2/$3';
```

Here is my controller

```
public function method( $lang = "en", country = NULL, city = NULL ){
    
    //do something
    
}
```

The main problem is if I open this link **http://example.com/link/india** CI3 route takes india as language. So how to solve this problem?

Comment: what's the logic behind the 2nd group of routes?

Comment: This is for language. Check the method.

Comment: yes but why `$route['(:any)/link']` instead of `$route['link/(:any)']   `? I don't understand

Comment: en/link and link/india. The first one for language and the 2nd one for country name.

Comment: `$route['(:any)/link']` won't work, AFAIK... use the same route for both: `$route['link/(:any)']` and check in your method, if the first parameter is 'en' or 'link' and go on from there...

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have to try using regex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241438/discussion-between-vickel-and-ashis-biswas).